# Text overlap on Zoom in

Tags: css, text, zooming

I have a div 960px wide which further has 2 divs inside it . One on the right and other one on the left hand.The right hand div has some text in it(in a p tag) and whenever I zoom in the text just overlaps and does not stay the same . It stays the same if i zoom out . 
the css for the text is as follows:

```
p.text
{
color:black;
/*font-size:15.5px;*/
font-size:0.9em;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:7px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
}
```

and the css for the div is

```
#wraper-second-paragraph
{
    width:460px;
    height:150px;
    border: dotted 2px green;
    margin-top:14px;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you in anticipation .

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    width:466px;
    height:150px;
    border: dotted 2px green;
    margin-top:14px;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

set your width in % rather than px it will work

## wraper-second-paragraph

```
{
    width:55%;
    height:150px;
    border: dotted 2px green;
    margin-top:14px;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
}
```